# OTRS - ticket from api, can't send email notification to customer

Tags: rest, otrs

I'm trying to send email notification to customer after ticket is created with OTRS rest api. I know that it's impossible only with api so I created notification that reacts on TicketCreated event. My problem is email recipent. Notification is working on hardcoded email but I want to send notification to customer from ticket. When I'm selecting "customers" in recipent groups it's not working for tickets from api. But it's working for tickets created in web interface - result is that customer receive 2 emails - one original and one from notification. What I'm doing wrong? How to set customer with api? Below is my request

```
{
"Ticket":{
"Title":"REST Create Test",
"Type":"Unclassified",
"Queue":"Raw",
"State":"open",
"Priority":"3 normal",
"CustomerUser":"customer.email@gmail.com"
},
"Article":{
"Subject":"some subject ",
"Body":"nice body",
"ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf8",
"From":"otrs@fancy.company"
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried the same, adding "CustomerID" field and got nothing

Answer (score 1):

Even if no customer found in backend passed via web service, notificator will try to send mail to first mail sender - "customer.email@gmail.com" in your case.

Keep in mind that NotificationEvent is transactional by default, so it works in TicketObject destructor.
So reasons are:

1. Destructor is not called (for example inside of scheduler tasks). In this case you must call destructor manually.
2. More likely that ticket attributes have been changed after calling TicketCreate. So when destructor is performed, one of your notification attributes (Queue, Service, etc.) doesn't match ticket attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue. Don't know why. I created ticket successfully via rest API.

Comment: is this an answer

Comment: ^^ No, Just to said that I have got same issue.

Comment: if it is no an answer , why did  you said it as answer , could you please remove it

Comment: Seem that I can not comment to question or answers

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution to fix it. Just modify or create new event in "Ticket Notifications". Add event create ticket and set ticket filter is "open", "close" [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzdtQ.png)